# JSF - template and ajax call - best practices

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets

I'll try to explain my dubt in very few line of codes :

`template.xhtml` - here i load a page named as a get parameter (ex. index.xhtml?page=homepage => i load homepage.xhtml)

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" id="content">
    <c:catch>
        <ui:include src="#{selector.page}.xhtml" />
    </c:catch>
</h:panelGroup>
```

`homepage.xhtml` - my own homepage (that will change if im logged or not)

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{!login.loggedIn}">
    <h:outputLabel styleClass="content_title" value="im not logged" />
</h:panelGroup>
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{login.loggedIn}">
    <h:outputLabel styleClass="content_title" value="im logged" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

`ajax call` - so that's the real problem; if i do a call like this :

```
<f:ajax event="action" execute="param1 param2" render=":content"/>
```

`selector bean` :

```
package model;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

@ManagedBean(name="selector")
@RequestScoped
public class Selector {
    @ManagedProperty(value="#{param.page}")
    private String page;

    public String getPage() {
        if(page.compareTo("")==0) {
            this.page="homepage";
        }
        return page;
    }

    public void setPage(String page) {
        this.page=page;
    }
}
```

I'll load the new data on the panelGroup `content`, which is defined on the template.

The trouble is that when i call this, i lost the `page parameter` (setted previously on the selector bean), and i can't reload the current page.

So, the trick for you is :

1 - put the bean SessionScoped?

2 - Pass trought the ajax call the get value?

3 - Define my own application in other way?

Any suggestion would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass it to the next request as hidden input value in the same form.

```
<h:inputHidden value="#{selector.page}" />
```

Comment: Uhm yeah. IN fact this sound very strange for me, because on "execute" i would like to pass only few parameter, not the whole form (as we have discussed last day). I have to understand this on this framework :)

Comment: Tried this way right now, unfortunatly don't load that content. I think i need (first) to set a value as default on my Selector Bean. Watch at the code updated : it doesnt get "index" when i call #{selector.page} on the template. Dunno why...

Comment: Oh no, yeah it works. I just need to call that inputhidden as "page" :) anyway i still get to set default value for the bean. Thanks for the tips BalusC, looks like you the master of JSF :)

Comment: added the actual Bean. It doest put "homepage" as default (if there aren't page=value parameter on get).

Comment: Use `if (page == null || page.trim().isEmpty())` instead of a compare to empty string.